Is it possible to change bundle identifier easily once xcode project is complete with firebase
Prior to starting the update, i was getting errors from Firebase that the bundle identifier was not working for the app i had created so in order to update my app, i created a new firebase project with the new bundle identifier and i created a new project in xcode using the new bundle id i created in firebase.  I was advised by AppStore Connect that i need to update my app.
I just finished preparing for the update, when archiving for new build, it wouldn't allow me to proceed as i had to change the bundle id as it wasn't working in firebase.  My bundle id changed from 'com..' to 'ca..'.
My question is am i able to change the bundle id easily in Xcode and Firebase so that i can still proceed with the update or do i have to submit a new app?
The last time i tried to just change the bundle id in Xcode and create a new project with the new bundle id, it was loaded with errors in Xcode so i started from new.  Is there any way to use the updated version i just completed and change the bundle id in Xcode and firebase without all the hassle or am i going to have to proceed with removing the old app and creating a new app in appstore connect?
